# How to assure client side data integrity

Tags: javascript, rest, client-side, hmac

For our web application, we want the client to be as thick as possible, and keep our server as thin as possible. The idea is to give the client all the necessary data, let the user interact with that data in a snappy Javascript application (currently GWT, but we are considering moving to Angular or Backbone). We would like to make the server completely stateless, which improves scalability and memory usage.

A fundamental problem of course is that there is some data a user is not allowed to alter. For example, when doing a password reset procedure, the user cannot change his username, because then he could alter somebody elses password. There is also a boolean that indicates if the user has passed the captcha, we cannot allow him to set that to true. And many other examples can be thought of.

The solution we thought of is the following: Together with these strings that a user cannot touch (we call them the priviledged information), we also add a signature. This is simply the concatenation of the priviledeg info, HMAC signed on the server with an AES key. When the data from the client returns we concatenate and sign the info again, and if the signatures are identical, we know that the client has not touched our info.

My questions: Does anybody see any weaknesses in this scheme, and can anybody point to resources (books, blogs) where more info about this subject can be found?

Comment: If you are happy with "our server loves to be attacked by hackers" then, yes, only perform validation in the client.

Comment: Of course we will do serverside validation. What I intent to do is store information in the client, that the client cannot alter (I will drop the requests if he does alter the info)

Comment: You'll also need to store a datetime in the priviledged info and in the server check that it's not an old request being replayed.

Comment: Possible flaw: once a client get the HMAC of a particular set of privileged info, he can reuse it for later requests, combining new user-provided info with old privileged info.

Comment: @thesaurier_rex almost a year has passed, can you please share the approach you have considered for security. Also share references if any you have came across.

Comment: This is a great question. But no one from angular community bother to answer it. Its such a shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this question after several years: The thing I suggested was basically the same as Json Web Tokens (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token). The idea I suggested was correct, but of course you should use established libraries instead of rolling your own.